# How to create a CSS Grid with max width for main content and min width for sidebar?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a two column CSS grid with maximum width for the main content (800px) and a minimum width 200px for sidebar: https://codepen.io/dash/pen/gOmXqGr

The grid should be responsive:

1. The yellow sidebar should shrink but at least have 200px width.
2. The orange main content containing an image should have a maximum width of 800px and shrink if needed.

My `minmax` try does not work. Any ideas?

**Code:**

```
    html {font-family: Arial, sans-serif;}
    ul {margin: 0; list-style: none;}
    
    .theme-hero {
        display: grid;
        gap: 8px 32px;
        grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 800px) minmax(200px, auto);
        grid-template-rows: auto;
            grid-template-areas: 
            "breadcrumb ."
            "theme-img sidebar";
        max-width: 1400px;
    }
    
    .theme-hero-breadcrumb {
        grid-area: breadcrumb;
        background: gray;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .theme-hero-showcase {
        grid-area: theme-img;
        background: orange;
        max-width: 800px;
    }
    
    .theme-hero-sidebar {
        grid-area: sidebar;
        background: yellow;
    }
```

```
    <div class=theme-hero>
        <div class=theme-hero-breadcrumb>breadcrumb</div>
        <div class=theme-hero-showcase><img src=https://via.placeholder.com/800x600 alt></div>
        <div class=theme-hero-sidebar>sidebar</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This page has an example for your issue : https://codepen.io/faelplg/pen/RJJraB

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but I think the problem is the image. It won't allow the div to shrink.

You can img max-width/max-height to make it more responsive.

```
img{
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html {font-family: Arial, sans-serif;}
ul {margin: 0; list-style: none;}

img{
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
}

.theme-hero {
    display: grid;
    gap: 8px 32px;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 800px) minmax(200px, auto);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-areas: 
        "breadcrumb ."
        "theme-img sidebar";
    max-width: 1400px;
}

.theme-hero-breadcrumb {
    grid-area: breadcrumb;
    background: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.theme-hero-showcase {
    grid-area: theme-img;
    background: orange;
    max-width: 800px;
}

.theme-hero-sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class=theme-hero>
    <div class=theme-hero-breadcrumb>breadcrumb</div>
    <div class=theme-hero-showcase><img src=https://via.placeholder.com/800x600 alt></div>
    <div class=theme-hero-sidebar>sidebar</div>
</div>
```